# How to stop Excel from generating lots of rows and columns when making a new file?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When I open a new file in Excel, it makes a large amount of rows and columns, instead of a set amount. How do I delete all these columns and rows? They are useless to me.

Comment: Surely you don't want a new sheet with only `A1` visible.  How do you define what's useful or useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These empty rows and columns are there so you can enter data in them if you wish, but are not saved so should not affect file size or performance. There is no way to hide them without resizing the excel window

Answer (score 1):

Just for any doubters of @BlueDrink9's answer, try this:

**FIRST**

Open a new file, but do not enter anything yet.  Print the sheet and you should see this:

[image: Print of blank sheet]

Note:  If you don't see "We didn't find anything to print" you probably have some cell populated in you default template.  I'm not going to go into that here!

**SECOND**

Go to Page Setup: Sheet and ensure the "Gridlines" is checked.

Type "Test" in cell `A1`.

Print the sheet and you should see this (I'm showing print preview here):

[image: Test printed]

Only Test is printed and the only border displayed is around cell `A1`.